# Matlab uitable data selection

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-guide, matlab-uitable

I have Uitable with data read from a AScii file.

1. I want to select columns using mouse and also using checkboxes. I tried a lot but i cannot figure out how to select uitable column using mouse and getting that data.
2. Also I am trying to insert checkbox in the last row of the uitable, so when user selects checkbox, particular column is selected.

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should edit the `CellSelectionCallback` and the `CellEditCallback` properties of your table.

```
   set(myTable,`CellSelectionCallback`,@CallBack)
```

In order to see what columns/rows were selected, use the event data that you receive in your callback.

```
  function CallBack(hObj,evt)   
      disp(evt);
  end
```

As far as I know, there is no way to discover what columns are currently selected when the callback is not fired.

Comment: Hello Andrey, Thanks for your response. When i followed your instructions i was getting indices, but i want to get the data instead of indicies.

Comment: @SatyaVamsi, getting the data is much easier - use get(myTable,'Data'). Filter it by the indexes in evt

Comment: I trying to filter the data, but i was getting wrong data, Could you please help me how to get selected data

Answer (score 3):

To handle clicks on the column headers, one must go to [undocumented territory](http://undocumentedmatlab.com/blog/uitable-sorting/):

```
%# old UITABLE (based on Swing JTable, instead of the new JIDE-based)
[hTable,hContainer] = uitable('v0', 'Parent',gcf, ...
    'Data',magic(7), 'ColumnNames',cellstr(num2str((1:7)','C%d'))');
set(hContainer, 'Units','normalized', 'Position',[0 0 1 1])

%# handle mouse clicks on table headers
jTableHeader = hTable.getTable().getTableHeader();
h = handle(jTableHeader, 'CallbackProperties');
set(h, 'MousePressedCallback',...
    @(src,evt) disp( src.columnAtPoint(evt.getPoint())+1 ))  %# zero-based index
```

[image: screenshot]