# Clickable uitable row title MATLAB

Tags: matlab, user-interface, matlab-uitable

Does anyone know how to make row's titles (grey cells) in a uitable clickable in a Matlab GUI ? I am only able to get clickable cells within the table.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Matlab uitable data selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11103354/matlab-uitable-data-selection)

Answer (score 0):

You can't - at least not in any documented manner.

The only option is getting at the underlying java-table.
You could check http://undocumentedmatlab.com/ searching for `uitable` on this issue - it will yield several results that might help you get started.

Comment: I don't quite understand - you can freely search&read undocumentedmatlab.com, you don't have to pay for anything (except for if you want to buy the advertised book). But you won't find a solution thats ready for copy&paste...